# How to Replace IP field in Rewrite Condition

Tags: htaccess

`.htaccess` file contains below excerpt to block specific files and folders.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wp-login.php|wp-admin
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123.456.789.
RewriteRule . - [R=404,L]
```

I need to replace `123.456.789` field with my current IP which can be retrieved from:

```
w -h | awk '{print $3}' | head -1
```

How can I replace IP field in `.htaccess` file by my current IP grabbed from `w` and save it again to `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In case someone needs, it is:

```
sed -i "s/RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} \!\^[0-9,\.]*/RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} \!\^$(w -h | awk '{print $3}' | head -1)/g" .htaccess
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache is stateless and this is extra true regarding .htaccess files. This means you can add any directive on the fly. You could create a cron script and have it run every minute, make your script run your 'w -h | awk '{print $3}' | head -1' and insert the relevant information into the .htaccess file in the proper directive syntax 'RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xxx.xxx.xxx.'

Since apache is stateless, it reads that .htaccess file for every single request to any directory in or below that .htaccess, so your directive will go into affect immediately without needing to restart apache.